# Mesh + Armature Problem

Tags: mesh, armature

I finished modeling a LEGO man, so I decided to rig him.
After I rigged him, everything was fine:
https://youtu.be/ahPx-qFXO4o

But, when I tried to move the hips or body, the other parts were glitched out and didn't move correctly:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjmQoTe8Xlg&feature=youtu.be

Would really appreciate it if someone told me what the issue is. Thanks :]

Comment: Both YouTube videos are private.

Comment: What technique were you using for rigging and weight painting?

Comment: @LukaŠimić what do you mean? i joined all parts of the LEGO guy with ctrl + j and parented the Mesh and Armature with automatic weights. I then saw none of the parts were moving in relation to the bones, so I manually assigned all the specific parts to their specific bones.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally fixed it
if anyone has this problem, just recreate the bone structure and it should work :)

Comment: Can you add details to your answer, so others can follow the steps you propose?

Comment: @someonewithpc I just recreated the bone structure by deleting what i had before and making a new armature. Once that had been done, I joined all seperate parts of the mesh together with ctrl + j and parented it to the armature with automatic weights.

Comment: @xWeasel I'm not sure if the suggestion to redo a big chunk of the work is a welcome suggestion, even though we know sometimes it happens that way. However, I think your issue could have been adressed more easily If you had provided your blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ This way other users can examine what's wrong, and save you some time plus show you what actually caused it. Proper weighting of characters has a lot of catches and gotchas, so it's difficult for others to know which one was the issue THIS TIME  :)

Comment: @aliasguru i see what you mean, but unfortunately i don't have the blend file anymore, so that's the only solution i came up with :l